# std::cout Dosen't Print What I Want?

Tags: c++

```
void menuWaterMark() {
std::cout << std::endl;
std::cout << " __                  __        __             ______   __            __" << std::endl;
std::cout << "/  |                /  |      /  |           /      \ /  |          /  |" << std::endl;
std::cout << "$$ |        ______  $$ |   __ $$ |   __     /$$$$$$  |$$ | __    __ $$ |____" << std::endl;
std::cout << "$$ |       /      \ $$ |  /  |$$ |  /  |    $$ |  $$/ $$ |/  |  /  |$$     \\" << std::endl;
std::cout << "$$ |       $$$$$$  |$$ |_/$$/ $$ |_/$$/     $$ |      $$ |$$ |  $$ |$$$$$$$  |" << std::endl;
std::cout << "$$ |       /    $$ |$$   $$<  $$   $$<      $$ |   __ $$ |$$ |  $$ |$$ |  $$ |" << std::endl;
std::cout << "$$ |_____ /$$$$$$$ |$$$$$$  \ $$$$$$  \  __ $$ \__/  |$$ |$$ \__$$ |$$ |__$$ |" << std::endl;
std::cout << "$$       |$$    $$ |$$ | $$  |$$ | $$  |/  |$$    $$/ $$ |$$    $$/ $$    $$/" << std::endl;
std::cout << "$$$$$$$$/  $$$$$$$/ $$/   $$/ $$/   $$/ $$/  $$$$$$/  $$/  $$$$$$/  $$$$$$$/" << std::endl;}
```

So What's The Problem Here?

Comment: what should it print? what does it print? you need to tell us what the problem is

Comment: If it does not print what you want .. what _does_ it print?

Comment: A backslash character is an escape character, so to get a single backslash you need two of them to escape the backslash.  Or use raw string literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `\` character:

```
void menuWaterMark() {
std::cout << std::endl;
std::cout << " __                  __        __             ______   __            __" << std::endl;
std::cout << "/  |                /  |      /  |           /      \\ /  |          /  |" << std::endl;
std::cout << "$$ |        ______  $$ |   __ $$ |   __     /$$$$$$  |$$ | __    __ $$ |____" << std::endl;
std::cout << "$$ |       /      \\ $$ |  /  |$$ |  /  |    $$ |  $$/ $$ |/  |  /  |$$     \\\\" << std::endl;
std::cout << "$$ |       $$$$$$  |$$ |_/$$/ $$ |_/$$/     $$ |      $$ |$$ |  $$ |$$$$$$$  |" << std::endl;
std::cout << "$$ |       /    $$ |$$   $$<  $$   $$<      $$ |   __ $$ |$$ |  $$ |$$ |  $$ |" << std::endl;
std::cout << "$$ |_____ /$$$$$$$ |$$$$$$  \\ $$$$$$  \\  __ $$ \\__/  |$$ |$$ \\__$$ |$$ |__$$ |" << std::endl;
std::cout << "$$       |$$    $$ |$$ | $$  |$$ | $$  |/  |$$    $$/ $$ |$$    $$/ $$    $$/" << std::endl;
std::cout << "$$$$$$$$/  $$$$$$$/ $$/   $$/ $$/   $$/ $$/  $$$$$$/  $$/  $$$$$$/  $$$$$$$/" << std::endl;}
```

Or even nicer do it with a raw string literal:

```
void menuWaterMark() {

    auto watermark{ 
R"(
$$ |        ______  $$ |   __ $$ |   __     /$$$$$$  |$$ | __    __ $$ |____ 
$$ |       /      \ $$ |  /  |$$ |  /  |    $$ |  $$/ $$ |/  |  /  |$$     \\
$$ |       $$$$$$  |$$ |_/$$/ $$ |_/$$/     $$ |      $$ |$$ |  $$ |$$$$$$$  |
$$ |       /    $$ |$$   $$<  $$   $$<      $$ |   __ $$ |$$ |  $$ |$$ |  $$ |
$$ |_____ /$$$$$$$ |$$$$$$  \ $$$$$$  \  __ $$ \__/  |$$ |$$ \__$$ |$$ |__$$ |
$$       |$$    $$ |$$ | $$  |$$ | $$  |/  |$$    $$/ $$ |$$    $$/ $$    $$/
$$$$$$$$/  $$$$$$$/ $$/   $$/ $$/   $$/ $$/  $$$$$$/  $$/  $$$$$$/  $$$$$$$/ 
)"
};

    std::cout << watermark;
}
```

Now you don't need to escape your special characters and your picture is also pretty in code